# Reasons for JPA Transaction to be Aborted?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, transactions, abort

I am having no luck searching for possible reasons for a JPA transaction to be aborted.  We have an application that is deployed on JBoss EAP 2.6.0 using EclipseLink 2.4 as our JPA provider (instead of Hibernate).  Every so often we get this error and I am hoping somebody can give me any clue as to why.

**UPDATE**

We have isolated the problem to occur when our process makes a call to a RESTful webservice. Sometimes that call results in a

```
java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
```

After we get that exception, we start seeing the aborted transaction issue. Any thoughts on why getting a socket exception would abort a JPA transaction?

```
2014 Aug 27 13:46:06,055 MDT DVCProcessor [EJB default - 1] ERROR my.package.processor.ModemProcessor - : Failed migration, unexpected error
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException:
Exception Description: Error binding to externally managed transaction
Internal Exception: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016083: Can't register synchronization because the transaction is in aborted state
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:162) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar!/:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:252) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar!/:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:341) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar!/:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:238) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar!/:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar!/:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar!/:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar!/:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar!/:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar!/:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar!/:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar!/:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar!/:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) ~[jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar!/:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at my.package.datamodel.service.DVCDataService$$$view5.find(Unknown Source) ~[dvc-data-model-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]

<... snip ...>

        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncInvocationTask.run(AsyncInvocationTask.java:73) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar!/:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_55]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_55]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_55]
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:2.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.TransactionException:
Exception Description: Error binding to externally managed transaction
Internal Exception: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016083: Can't register synchronization because the transaction is in aborted state
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.TransactionException.errorBindingToExternalTransaction(TransactionException.java:71) ~[eclipselink-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractTransactionController.bindToCurrentTransaction(AbstractTransactionController.java:120) ~[eclipselink-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractTransactionController.registerSynchronizationListener(AbstractTransactionController.java:413) ~[eclipselink-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerWithTransactionIfRequired(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4379) ~[eclipselink-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.JTATransactionWrapper.registerUnitOfWorkWithTxn(JTATransactionWrapper.java:90) ~[eclipselink-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.getActivePersistenceContext(EntityManagerImpl.java:1738) ~[eclipselink-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.getActiveSession(EntityManagerImpl.java:1172) ~[eclipselink-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:662) ~[eclipselink-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:543) ~[eclipselink-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.find(AbstractEntityManager.java:193) ~[jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar!/:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        at my.package.datamodel.service.DVCDataService.find(DVCDataService.java:57) ~[dvc-data-model-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

<... snip ...>

        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar!/:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:250) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar!/:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
        ... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016083: Can't register synchronization because the transaction is in aborted state
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.registerSynchronizationImple(TransactionImple.java:370) ~[na:na]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.registerSynchronization(TransactionImple.java:351) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTATransactionController.registerSynchronization_impl(JTATransactionController.java:92) ~[eclipselink-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
        at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractTransactionController.bindToCurrentTransaction(AbstractTransactionController.java:116) ~[eclipselink-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0.v20120608-r11652]
        ... 121 common frames omitted
```